# Jenkins Remote Shell exporting vairables

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the [Publish over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) and can't figure out, how to source remote script to update my `PATH` before running another script?

Of course, I can run only one script, where I can source whatever I want, but I just can't source a first script where I export variables, and access these variables from another script.

Example: I have 3 scripts `changePath.sh`, `runChangingPath.sh`, `runAfterChangingPath.sh`

```
changePath.sh
   export PATH=xxx:$PATH   

runChangingPath.sh
   echo "PATH 1: "$PATH
   . ./changePath.sh
   echo "PATH 2:"$PATH     

runAfterChangingPath.sh
    echo "PATH 3: "$PATH
```

When I'm executing the following with Publisher:
    `./runChangingPath.sh`

It's echoing original path (say `/usr/bin`) after "PATH 1" label, then its echoing `xxx:/usr/bin` after "PATH 2" label. It is echoing as I expected.

But when I'm executing the following with Publisher:
    `./changePath.sh`
    `./runAfterChangingPath.sh`

I'm expecting the following : `PATH 3: xxx:/usr/bin`, but current outcome is `PATH 3: /usr/bin`.

I just don't understand why variable PATH exported in script `changePath.sh` is not persisted in calling shell.

PS: if I'm running the exact same thing directly with `ssh`, all results are the ones I'm expecting. So I truly seems to be related only to "SSH Publisher Plugin".